# STS error installing Grails, Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have installed STS 2.7.1 on windows 7 and now i am trying to install Groovy eclipse, Grails support and Grails extension on it but i keep getting error -

An error occured while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=com.springsource.sts.ide=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,action=).
Unable to read repository at http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e3.7/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_1.7.10.xx-20110811-0900-e37.jar.
Read timed out.

Any ideas what's happening here? i can get to this url through browser.

Thanks,
Gaurav

Comment: Usually I forget to run STS in admin-mode - otherwise I cannot install  any extensions. But I am not sure, whether your error message is the same. Just check, whether you run STS as administrator.

Comment: Thanks cruldolf. I have tried running it as admin but still getting the same error. Another thing i tried was to install eclipse and then install STS plugin on top of it. Still getting the same error - i am stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, i have finally managed to solve this.. Apparently, it didn't like my JDK version. I had to downgrade from JDK 7 to JDK6 U27 and it worked like a charm.